# Cannot create Entry widget with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm having some trouble creating an entry widget with tkinter. I've imported the necessary modules and have already created several buttons and check boxes. However I cannot figure out how to properly initialize the Entry. Here is my relevant code:

```
# Necessary Modules.------------------------------------------------------------
import win32com.client as win32
import re
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import tkinter.messagebox


# Class for selecting the file.-------------------------------------------------
class FilenameClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.location = 'User Import.txt'

    def getFile(self, identity):
        self.file_opt = options = {}
        options['defaultextension'] = '.txt'
        options['filetypes'] = [('Text Document (.txt)', '.txt'),
                                ('all files', '.*')]
        self.filename = askopenfilename(**self.file_opt)
        if self.filename:
            if 'User Import' in identity:
                self.location = self.filename
                app.get_txt_File['bg'] = '#0d0'
                user_file = open(self.filename, 'r')
                user_total = user_file.read()
                remove_lines = user_total.splitlines()
                for user in remove_lines:
                    regex_tab = re.compile('\\t')
                    user_info = regex_tab.split(user)
                    app.users.append(user_info)
            else:
                app.loadButton['bg'] = '#e10'


# Main Class.-------------------------------------------------------------------
class Application(Frame, Tk):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.users = []
        self.fileOBJtxt = FilenameClass()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):

        # Define the default values for the options for the buttons
        # Grid layout options
        self.rowconfigure(0, minsize=5)
        self.width = 54
        self.grid(padx=5)
        self.loadButton_gopt = {'row':1,'column':1,'padx': 2, 'pady': 5}
        self.loadButton_wopt = {'width': round(self.width),'bg':'#e10'}
        self.loadButton()
        self.trainingCheckBox()
        self.signatureInput()

    def loadButton(self):
        '''Button that calls the filename class which allows the user to select
        the text file they wish to use.'''

        self.get_txt_File = Button(self, text="Load User List", \
        command=lambda: self.fileOBJtxt.getFile('User Import'))
        for key, value in self.loadButton_wopt.items():
            self.get_txt_File[key] = value
        self.get_txt_File.grid(**self.loadButton_gopt)

    def trainingCheckBox(self):

        self.training_var = IntVar()
        self.training = Checkbutton(text="Include training video?", \
        variable=self.training_var).grid(row=2, sticky=W)

    def signatureInput(self):

        Label(text="Signature Name").grid(row=4, sticky=W)
        entry = Entry(bg='#fff', width=50)
        entry.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=4)     

# Initialization parameters.----------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Application()
    app.master.title('User Notification Tool')
    app.master.geometry('405x550+100+100')
    app.master.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    app.mainloop()
```

I'm not seeing any tracebacks, but I can't seem to get my Entry box to show up. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: added entire code.

Comment: Can you show the rest of your code?

Comment: Sure thing, see my edit for the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your entry field is you have not told it what frame/window to be placed in.

Change:

```
entry = Entry(bg='#fff', width=50)
```

To:

```
entry = Entry(self, bg='#fff', width=50)
```

Make sure you always provide the window/frame that a widget is going to be placed in as the first argument. In this case it is `self` as self refers to a frame.

Keep in mind that your program will not be able to `get()` the string inside of your entry field because you have not defined it as a class attribute. So most likely you will need to change

This:

```
entry = Entry(bg='#fff', width=50)
entry.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=4)
```

To This:

```
self.entry = Entry(self, bg='#fff', width=50)
self.entry.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=4)
```

This change will be necessary in order for the rest of your application to be able to read or write to the entry widget.

Comment: Cheers this worked perfectly. Thats good to know that in lieu of using master I still need to provide self. Thanks for catching the entry attribute as well, I haven't made it to implementing `get()` yet but you've saved me some time.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
entry = Entry(bg='#fff', width=50)
```

to

```
entry = tk.Entry(bg='#fff', width=50)
```

Comment: I tried doing that but I'm getting an undefined error. When I created my checkboxes I need only to have `Checkbutton`. Is there some reason that `Entry` specifically requires `tk.`? thanks for your response.

Comment: person: This is not accurate as the OP is not importing `tkinter as tk` but rather importing as *.

Comment: When I posted the answer, the import line wasn't there, just class Application(Frame, Tk). I made an assumption

Comment: Please update your answer to be consistent with the question, or if it ends up not being useful, consider deleting.

Comment: person: your assumption was still inaccurate because the OP had written `Application(Frame, Tk)` and not  `Application(tk.Frame, tk.Tk)`. If the OP had written `(tk.Frame, tk.Tk)` then your assumption would be accurate. I agree with @SamHartman. Now that you know your error you should update your answer to reflect the question. Or remove your post as providing wrong information can hurt the growth of other beginners and likely you will continue to get down votes on your answer.